# Netbeans on Ubuntu does not offer all project templates

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu

I am currently taking a course on distributed computing with Java. I am told to create a project in Netbeans by going to "File -> New Project -> Java Web -> Web Application", however, on my Ubuntu 12.04 Desktop (openjdk and netbeans installed through apt-get), when I click on "New Project", only the "Java", "NetBeans Modules", and "samples" categories are offered.

Netbeans installed on a windows computer appear to have many more listings under Categories when creating a new project in Netbeans. In particular, it offers "Java Web" under categories, and under that category a "Web Application" project is offered. Is there a package I need to install in order to get all the categories/project template listings? If not, how else might I work around the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to tools|plugins and install Java Web plugins (or J2EE, not sure about the exact word) or download all bundle from netbeans.org/downloads